# Epsilon and log functions

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I m trying this

```
T(n) \epsilon \left(\Theta(n^\log_22$\right) = $\Theta(n^\log_22 )$ = $\Theta(n)$
```

but i want below result. Is E sign is epsilon only . And also log bracket not coming properly and space before aND AFTER EPSILON NOT CORRECT.

[image]

Generally  online it is given as

```
\[

    $A(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_b a}) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 2} ) = \Theta(n)$

\]
```

so i am asking what these `\[` and `\]` brackets do.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- Don't use `\epsilon` for "element of"; instead, use the `\in` macro.
- You need to place curly braces around the material that's to be placed in the exponent positions.
- Don't switch in and out of math mode in one and the same equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$A(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_b a}) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 2} ) = \Theta(n)$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank u very much switching off nad on in  equation was giving 7 error.

Comment: whats the use of \[ \] placing equation between this

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary - I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by `[]`.

Comment: \[    $A(n) \in \Theta(n^{\log_b a}) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 2} ) = \Theta(n)$    \]  writing like this

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary - To the best of my knowledge, there are no square brackets in my code. What are you referring to?

Comment: just see the question again last part i have added another representation using [ ] .

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary - Now I get it. Use either `$ ... $` for inline-style math material or `\[ ... \]` for display-style math material, *but not both methods simultaneously*. My answer used inline-style math mode. If you want to typeset the material as a displayed equation, replace the first `$` symbol with `\[` and the second `$` symbol with `\]`.